# best way to manipulate strings in big data.table

Tags: r, data.table, strsplit, stringr

I have a 67MM row data.table with people names and surname separated by spaces. I just need to create a new column for each word.

Here is an small subset of the data:

```
n <- structure(list(Subscription_Id = c("13.855.231.846.091.000", 
"11.156.048.529.090.800", "24.940.584.090.830", "242.753.039.111.124", 
"27.843.782.090.830", "13.773.513.145.090.800", "25.691.374.090.830", 
"12.236.174.155.090.900", "252.027.904.121.210", "11.136.991.054.110.100"
), Account_Desc = c("AGUAYO CARLA", "LEIVA LILIANA", "FULLANA MARIA LAURA", 
"PETREL SERGIO", "IPTICKET SRL", "LEDESMA ORLANDO", "CATTANEO LUIS RAUL", 
"CABRAL CARMEN ESTELA", "ITURGOYEN HECTOR", "CASA CASILDO"), 
    V1 = c("AGUAYO", "LEIVA", "FULLANA", "PETREL", "IPTICKET", 
    "LEDESMA", "CATTANEO", "CABRAL", "ITURGOYEN", "CASA"), V2 = c("CARLA", 
    "LILIANA", "MARIA", "SERGIO", "SRL", "ORLANDO", "LUIS", "CARMEN", 
    "HECTOR", "CASILDO"), V3 = c(NA, NA, "LAURA", NA, NA, NA, 
    "RAUL", "ESTELA", NA, NA), `NA` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), .Names = c("Subscription_Id", "Account_Desc", "V1", "V2", 
"V3", NA), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000200788>)


require("data.table")
n <- data.table(n)
```

**Expected Output**

```
#           Subscription_Id         Account_Desc        V1      V2     V3 NA
# 1: 13.855.231.846.091.000         AGUAYO CARLA    AGUAYO   CARLA     NA NA
# 2: 11.156.048.529.090.800        LEIVA LILIANA     LEIVA LILIANA     NA NA
# 3:     24.940.584.090.830  FULLANA MARIA LAURA   FULLANA   MARIA  LAURA NA
```

### 1st Attempt

#### How to make this work would be the first question

```
library(stringr)
# This separates the strings, but i loose the Subscription_Id variable.
n[, str_split_fixed(Account_Desc, "[ +]", 4)]

# This doesn't work.
n[, paste0("V",1:4) := str_split_fixed(Account_Desc, "[ +]", 4)]
```

### 2nd Attempt

This works, but i seem to be doing the calculation 3 times. Not sure if its
the most effiecient way

```
cols = paste0("V",1:3)
for(j in 1:3){
  set(n,i=NULL,j=cols[j],value = sapply(strsplit(as.character(n$Account_Desc),"[ +]"), "[", j))
}
```

Let's use **big_n** to benchmarck

```
big_n <- data.table(Subscription_Id = rep(n[,Subscription_Id],1e7),
                    Account_Desc = rep(n[,Account_Desc],1e7)
                    )
```

Comment: Wait until `sep2` is implemented in `fread`? ;)

Comment: @Roland, I see your wink, but if I remember correctly, `fread` is not going to get a `fill` type argument (as is present in `read.table`) any time soon, which would mean it would have a hard time with "unbalanced" strings like these.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Ah, I didn't see that there are people with multiple given names. I usually forget that since I'm one of the poor guys who's got only one.

Comment: `read.csv` might take years

Comment: there are 2 FR's (already out there) that could really help you out here - one is having `rbindlist` work with lists of vectors, and the other one is having a `fill` argument for it; until those are implemented I think your 2nd solution (with possibly some minor adjustments) is the way to go

Comment: ... and somehow, nobody has pointed out your timing is wrong. You're splitting just 10 rows, not 1e7 :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto I rep the ten rows to 10e7 in big_n, (in total there are 100 MM rows in big_n). Not sure if this is equivalent, but it works for reproducibility.

Comment: @MartínBel, look at what you have in your `set_method` function. You have hard-coded `n$Account_Desc` in your `strsplit` line.

Comment: Following @Arun's recommendation about moving `strsplit` out of the loop makes a big difference, as does using `strsplit(input, " ", fixed = TRUE)`. Incorporating both those suggestions reduced the time I was getting on 1e5 rows from ~ 25 seconds to ~ 9 seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't work with datasets anywhere near this scale, so I have no idea if this is going to be of use or not. One thing that comes to mind is to use a `matrix` and matrix indexing.

Since I'm impatient, I've only tried it on 1e5 rows on my slow system :-)

#### Create your sample data

```
big_n <- data.table(Subscription_Id = rep(n[,Subscription_Id],1e5),
                    Account_Desc = rep(n[,Account_Desc],1e5))
```

#### Write a function to create your matrix

```
StringMat <- function(input) {
  Temp <- strsplit(input, " ", fixed = TRUE)
  Lens <- vapply(Temp, length, 1L)
  A <- unlist(Temp, use.names = FALSE)
  Rows <- rep(sequence(length(Temp)), Lens)
  Cols <- sequence(Lens)
  m <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(Temp), ncol = max(Lens),
              dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("V", sequence(max(Lens)))))
  m[cbind(Rows, Cols)] <- A
  m
}
```

#### Time it and view the output

```
system.time(outB1 <- cbind(big_n, StringMat(big_n$Account_Desc)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.524   0.000   4.533 
outB1
#                 Subscription_Id         Account_Desc        V1      V2     V3
#       1: 13.855.231.846.091.000         AGUAYO CARLA    AGUAYO   CARLA     NA
#       2: 11.156.048.529.090.800        LEIVA LILIANA     LEIVA LILIANA     NA
#       3:     24.940.584.090.830  FULLANA MARIA LAURA   FULLANA   MARIA  LAURA
#       4:    242.753.039.111.124        PETREL SERGIO    PETREL  SERGIO     NA
#       5:     27.843.782.090.830         IPTICKET SRL  IPTICKET     SRL     NA
#      ---                                                                     
#  999996: 13.773.513.145.090.800      LEDESMA ORLANDO   LEDESMA ORLANDO     NA
#  999997:     25.691.374.090.830   CATTANEO LUIS RAUL  CATTANEO    LUIS   RAUL
#  999998: 12.236.174.155.090.900 CABRAL CARMEN ESTELA    CABRAL  CARMEN ESTELA
#  999999:    252.027.904.121.210     ITURGOYEN HECTOR ITURGOYEN  HECTOR     NA
# 1000000: 11.136.991.054.110.100         CASA CASILDO      CASA CASILDO     NA
```

#### Correct the `set_method` function and compare timings

```
set_method <- function(DT){
  cols = paste0("V",1:3)
  for(j in 1:3){
    set(DT,i=NULL,j=cols[j],
        value = sapply(strsplit(as.character(DT[, Account_Desc, with = TRUE]),
                                "[ +]"), "[", j))
  }
}

system.time(set_method(big_n))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  25.319   0.022  25.586
```

#### Reset the "big_n" dataset and try out `str_split_fixed` (ouch!)

```
big_n[, c("V1", "V2", "V3") := NULL]

library(stringr)
system.time(outBrodie <- cbind(big_n, as.data.table(str_split_fixed(
  big_n$Account_Desc, "[ +]", 4))))
#    user  system elapsed 
# 204.966   0.514 206.910
```

Comment: +1 I like the optimizations. However, you can save some additional time by creating a character matrix `m` instead of a logical matrix. I recommend replacing `NA` (logical) with `NA_character_`. This avoids type conversion when adding the strings to the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT 3: Stealing Arun's blood and sweat:

```
cbind(n, as.data.table(str_split_fixed(n$Account_Desc, "[ +]", 4)))
```

This avoids the potentially costly `by` and produces the same result (plus the original name column).

EDIT2: as per Arun's comment, maybe:

```
n.2[, c(paste0("V", 1:4)):=as.list(str_split_fixed(Account_Desc, "[ +]", 4)), by=Subscription_Id]
```

But you still have the `by`.  Old way:

```
n[, as.list(str_split_fixed(Account_Desc, "[ +]", 4)), by=Subscription_Id]
```

produces:

```
  #            Subscription_Id        V1      V2     V3 V4
  #  1: 13.855.231.846.091.000    AGUAYO   CARLA          
  #  2: 11.156.048.529.090.800     LEIVA LILIANA          
  #  3:     24.940.584.090.830   FULLANA   MARIA  LAURA   
  #  4:    242.753.039.111.124    PETREL  SERGIO          
  #  5:     27.843.782.090.830  IPTICKET     SRL          
  #  6: 13.773.513.145.090.800   LEDESMA ORLANDO          
  #  7:     25.691.374.090.830  CATTANEO    LUIS   RAUL   
  #  8: 12.236.174.155.090.900    CABRAL  CARMEN ESTELA   
  #  9:    252.027.904.121.210 ITURGOYEN  HECTOR          
  # 10: 11.136.991.054.110.100      CASA CASILDO
```

EDIT: word of warning, some `stringr` functions can be slow (not sure if this one is).  If this is still slow for your process, you may want to write your own function using `strsplit` and something to pad it to the appropriate length.

Comment: @Arun I'm happy to steal your answer, but you should probably post it as a faster alternative.  In this case it's fairly different as opposed to a tweak.

Comment: I think this is way slower than OP's 2nd implementation

Comment: @Arun all of the attempts in this answer are much slower

Comment: than OP's 2nd implementation; and it's because the `stringr` function is super slow

Comment: but it's not :) regular `strsplit` is orders of magnitude faster; the bottleneck is not splitting - it's combining

Comment: OP's 2nd solution does the binding and that's again orders of magnitude faster than whatever `stringr` does

Comment: as you mentioned previously, Subscription_Id is unique.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I actually remember a question where you noted this a few weeks ago, and that's why I put in my first edit at the very bottom before this conversation exploded; either way, even fixing that looks like this is not the best way.

Comment: Most of the stringr functions just wrap the base R regular expression functions. `str_split_fixed()` does a little more than the base functions, so it's a little slower.