# How to select phrase/term based on another column value from phrases with differently ordered words?

Tags: r

I have been trying to fiddle with this tricky problem and have been searching for the optimal solution. Basically it is sort of finding phrases with same/similar combination of words ( and select only one with a higher value based on a second column value). So far I have used **expand.grid()** and **agrep** but had no success.

The other option I am thinking at last resort is to go through every single term and split word by space and try to match possible combinations against all terms, using few **for loops**. But the cost of computation will be too high since I have considerably bigger size data.

Below is the sample data:

```
sample <- data.frame(Terms = I(c( "clamp","rod","rod44","rod21","rod21","rod13","rod21","rod12",
                              "rod iron plate","metal plate","plate metal","plates",
                              "rods", "plate rod iron", "11mm rod", "25mm rod", "40mm plate","rod 11mm")), 
              Weights = I(c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
                            50, 45, 60, 20, 30, 100, 30, 20, 40, 50))
              )
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**   :

```
     Terms Weights
  rod 11mm      50
  25mm rod      20
40mm plate      40
     clamp      10
plate rod iron  100
plate metal     60   ..........
```

Comment: Not an answer but what you're doing is ngrams related.  An R search with this may be useful.  Perhaps think about steming as well.  But honestly splitting on spaces (and using a proper vectorized approach) is likely much faster than something using `agrep` which is using a complex algorithm.

Comment: If you do go the splitting route, look at @AnandaMahto 's potential solution in this **[SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733345/best-way-to-manipulate-strings-in-big-data-table/21736272#21736272)**

Comment: Thanks @BrodieG. I will take a look at it if I won't find the simplest approach. 

I just came across a new function **permn()** from package **combinat** that at least gives all possible combination/permutations. I am going to try and see :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that works with your data but the problem may be more complex:

```
library(splitstackshape)
dat2 <- splitstackshape:::read.concat(sample[, 1], "Term", " ")

dat2[dat2 == ""] <- NA
key <- apply(dat2, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = " "))

dat3 <- split(sample, key)
do.call(rbind, lapply(dat3, function(x) {
    x[which.max(x$Weights), ]
}))

##                         Terms Weights
## 11mm rod             rod 11mm      50
## 25mm rod             25mm rod      20
## 40mm plate         40mm plate      40
## clamp                   clamp      10
## iron plate rod plate rod iron     100
## metal plate       plate metal      60
## plates                 plates      20
## rod                       rod      10
## rod12                   rod12      10
## rod13                   rod13      10
## rod21                   rod21      10
## rod44                   rod44      10
## rods                     rods      30
```

Comment: Thank Tyler. I tried using your logic on a little bigger piece of the data and it doesn't give the correct results. I think its the **split** function that doesn't give correct split results.

Comment: Without isolating what the problem is we can't be of much help.  Isolate the problem and then add that corner case to the data set you supply above.

Comment: I have updated data and tried with your suggested code and seems like its not reading correctly using **read.table**. I am going to try and read it differently, may be using regex and see if it works.

Comment: I got annoyed with `read.table` and went with the `library(splitstackshape)` package.  I think it can be done with `read.table` but haven't invested the time to figure out how.

Comment: Ha..Thanks Tyler. I also figured out another way to read it using below code but your definitely looks much nicer. I didn't know about **splitstackshape** lib.


`url_parts_search <- lapply(sample$Terms, strsplit, ' ', perl=TRUE)
dat2 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind.fill.matrix, lapply(url_parts_search, function(x) do.call (rbind, x))))`